# Linq-to-SQL group by date-periods depending on a parameter (daily, Monthly....)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to make a Linq to SQL query that returns Date grouping results. The challenge is about grouping daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly depends of a enumerable parameter (periodicity). Below, my current Linq to SQL query:

```
var TotalGroupedInvoices = from c in entidades.InvoicesView
                     group c by (periodo == periodicity.Daily) ? c.InvoiceDate.Date :
                                      period == periodicity.Weekly?     c.InvoiceDate.Date.AddDays(-(double)c.InvoiceDate.DayOfWeek) :
                                      period == periodicity.Monthly? new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year,c.InvoiceDate.Month ,1) :
                                      period == periodicity.Quarterly? new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year, c.InvoiceDate.Month - (c.InvoiceDate.Month % 3) +1, 1) :
                                      period == periodicity.Anual ? new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year, 1, 1) : inicio into Periods
                     select new
                     {

                         period = Periods.Key,
                         Total = Periodos.Sum(c => c.Total)
                     };
```

For clarification, take a look at the quarterly period code fragment:

```
period == periodicity.Quarterly? new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year, c.InvoiceDate.Month - (c.InvoiceDate.Month % 3) +1, 1)
```

Thus, for dates into first quarter like: January/12/2012, January/15/2012, or March/20/2012 i get all of them grouped at the quarter begginig: January/1/2012, so it's works as expected.

First I wonder about the query efficiency. What do you think about this? Maybe it would be better to translate periods in integers for SQL Server efficiency and re-translate to date periods on client, but i'm not sure about this.

On the other hand, the weekly group works grouping dates weekly into the first sunday of each week:

```
period == periodicity.Weekly? c.InvoiceDate.Date.AddDays(-(double)c.InvoiceDate.DayOfWeek)
```

...but that's incorrect for me because i'm from Spain and weeks start on Monday. How can i fix the week groups to take this into account?

So, summarizing:

- What about this Linq to SQL query efficiency?
- How can i group weekly by this but considering weeks from Monday to Sunday?

Thanks a lot!
PD: sorry for my English level.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the first part, you don't really want to transmit the enum value into the databaes and let it make the decision of which code branch to use.  You have all the information to make the decision locally.

```
Expression<Func<InvoicesView, DateTime>> groupingExpr = c => c.InvoiceDate.Date;

if (period == periodicity.Weekly)
{
  groupingExpr = c => c.InvoiceDate.Date.AddDays(-(double)c.InvoiceDate.DayOfWeek);
}
else if (period == periodicity.Monthly)
{
  groupingExpr = c => new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year,c.InvoiceDate.Month ,1);
}
else if (period == periodicity.Quarterly)
{
  groupingExpr = c => new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year, c.InvoiceDate.Month - (c.InvoiceDate.Month % 3) +1, 1);
}
else if (period == periodicity.Anual
{
  groupingExpr = c => new DateTime(c.InvoiceDate.Year, 1, 1);
}


var TotalGroupedInvoices = entidades.InvoicesView 
  .GroupBy(groupingExpr)
  .Select(grouped => new {
    period = grouped.Key,
    Total = grouped.Sum(c => c.Total)   
  });
```

---

Here's the best I can do to blend the groupingExpr with query comprehension syntax:

```
var TotalGroupedInvoices = from grouped in entidades.InvoicesView.GroupBy(groupingExpr)
  select new {
    period = grouped.Key,
    Total = grouped.Sum(c => c.Total)   
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, i'm a rookie with Linq-to-SQL and didn't notice the difference between my code and yours, I'll try your code with LinqPad tool and study the differences. I'll return in a few hours and post any doubts or sets as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FranCD I'll change the code to make the difference more clear.  You may want to examine groupingExpr in the debugger.

Comment: Hi David, the new code is really clear and, as you said, generated SQL is shorter with your approach. I wonder if is possible to use the groupingExpression as a part of a Linq query writed with comprehension syntax (as a rookie, this syntax seems to be clearest). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer the second part, you just need to do some "day" arithmetic. You can do this inline or as a separate function (eg extension method):

```
public static DateTime FirstDayOfWeek (this DateTime date)  
{  
  double offset = (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday) ? -6 : (DayOfWeek.Monday - date.DayOfWeek);  
  return date.AddDays(offset);  
}
```

Then in your LINQ:

```
period == periodicity.Weekly ? c.InvoiceDate.FirstDayOfWeek
```

However, given that you are retrieving this from SQL you may just want to look at the date functions there eg DATEPART and return them in your queries

Comment: Thanks a lot, i try this solutions within a few hours and post any doubts or sets as accepted answer.

Comment: Great! Note I've not claimed to answer the first part of your question - I'd experiment with different approaches to see performance. For readability I'd consider having a separate function to calculate a representative period date

Comment: Since i'm writing Linq-to-SQL, there is a problem with your approach: the method 'System.DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(System.DateTime)' doesn't support SQL conversion. So, is possible another workaroud? Thanks

Comment: For LINQ to SQL it looks like you have to do it inline (I'd only tested on LINQ to objects). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609596/why-is-linq-to-sql-tricked-by-an-extension-method-what-now